# how to add dynamic json object to jq bash

Tags: bash, jq

I need to add a dynamic JSON object according to arguments passed using a bash.Currently, I am abale to generate dynamic tables object but in output it is appending as a string. Please help me.
`bash demo.bash sarika@gmail.com abc demo h`
I have code:

```
Tables=$(  for i in "${@:3}"; do
                jq -n \
                  --arg tn $i \
                  '{"table_name":$tn}'
                done )

echo $Tables |jq '.'
tab=$( echo $Tables |jq '.'  )
# tab= $Tables |jq '.'

JSON_STRING=$( jq -n \
                  --arg gb "$VALUE" \
                  --arg tables "$tab" \
                  '{"email":$gb,"tables":[($tables)]}'\
                  )
```

Output it is giving:

```
{
  "email": "sarika@gmail.com",
  "tables": [
    "{\n \"table_name\": \"demo\",\n}\n{\n \"table_name\": \"h\",\n}"
  ]
}
```

I Need a result like:

```
{
  "email": "sarika@gmail.com",
  "tables": [
    {
      "table_name": "table1"
    },
    {
      "table_name": "table2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're looking for this:

```
tables=$(for i in "${@:3}"; do jq -n --arg tn "$i" '{"table_name": $tn}'; done | jq -s .)

jq -n \
    --arg gb "$VALUE" \
    --argjson tables "$tables" \
    '{"email": $gb, "tables": $tables}'
```

What was wrong, and how I fixed it:

- The `jq` in the first loop produces JSON objects of the form `{"table_name": $tn}`. To form a JSON array from these objects, with proper `,` separator between objects, you need to pipe these objects through `jq -s .`
- To pass a JSON object as argument, use `--argjson` instead of `--arg`
- To embed a JSON array `$tables`, write `"tables": $tables` instead of `"tables": [$tables]` which would create an unnecessary array
- It was not an error, but a very bad had habit to not use double-quote variables used as command line arguments